# why request dispatcher parameters available to the receiving servlet only

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners, servletcontextlistener

my index.jsp

```
 <%
    String token = "abc"
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/LoginServlet?Token="+token).forward(request,response);
    %>
```

actually before going to LoginServlet control will go to  ServletFilter  url mapped to /*(in web.xml) , so every request go through this ServletFilter

in ServletFilter 
request.getparameter("Token") returns null, but in LoginServlet token is returning "abc"

Please suggest me how to get the token in ServletFilter

Comment: Reconsider your design seriously: a JSP should not use scriptlets. A view should not forward to a controller. It's the other way round: request should go to a servlet controller, which should then forward to a view, which generates HTML (and does only that).

Comment: one instance of project is in production,project design can't change now. Let me know is there any way to get the Token in ServletFilter using request.getParameter("Token") method only

Comment: set the attribute in request and forward it then get the attribute form request in filter

Comment: use to get request.getParameter("Token") method only

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused in way sendRedirect and forward works.

flow of filters using forward and sendRedirect is like shown below,

### forward

```
1. Filter (Your request came here first, before JSP called, and 
   you are trying to get "Token" parameter which is no where set yet)

2. JSP (Your JSP setting parameter, as it is forward, control will not 
   go to Filter again)

3. Servlet (you are accessing parameter, which is set in JSP 
   and you got the "Token" parameter)
```

### sendRedirect

```
1. Filter(Your request came here first, before JSP called, and you are trying
   to get "Token" parameter which is no where set yet)

2. JSP(Your JSP setting parameter, as it is redirect, control will go to browser 
   back and spwan new request,which intercept by web.xml and calls Filter again) 

3. Filter (So you got data here)

4. Servlet (So you got data here)
```

### Try this and see output

```
  <%

    String token = "abc";
    // Below 2 lines, try commenting each and see flow
    //request.getRequestDispatcher("/LoginServlet?Token="+token).forward(request,response);   
    response.sendRedirect("LoginServlet?Token="+token);

   %>
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer, using sendRedirect secondtime process of filter got the Token with new request object. But how to get the Token First time (processing of filter), using request.getParameter("token) ?